# iMessage on Mac not working when using VPN

Tags: macos, messages, vpn

iMessage stopped working properly when I use VPN on my Macbook Pro (Mavericks), making me unable to send or receive messages.

It says the user is not registered and highlighted in red/pink, but after I disconnect VPN, everything works fine.

[image]

Comment: depending on your needs you could just uncheck the box for "send all traffic over VPN"

Answer (score 1):

Make sure **TCP port 5223** is open through the VPN—this port is required by iMessage.

Comment: @patrix Thanks, but without knowing the VPN being used, it's impossible to explain how exactly to open the port for Bill C, and out of scope of Ask Different.

Comment: I use [blackVPN's OpenVPN application](https://www.blackvpn.com/setup/mac-os-x/). How do I open **port 5223**?

Comment: @Feng As mentioned, the specifics of VPN configuration are off-topic here (besides, I have no knowledge of that VPN). I suggest you look through the documentation for that specific VPN.